# How can I plot the derived function of cubic spline interpolation?

Tags: matlab, plot, spline, cubic

I want to ask how I can plot the derived function of cubic spline interpolation? I show how I did it in my code. The error was:

Error using plot
Invalid second data argument
Error in function_MTU4000_Real (line 90)
plot1=plot(x1,Speed1,'b');

```
%calculation of lifting of intake valve (approximation spline function)

x1=0.0:0.1:202.1;
y1=xlsread('Steuerzeiten_Schrittweite_MTU4000.xlsx',1,'D2:D2023');
Lifting1=spline(x1,y1);
x2=202.1:0.1:701.9;
Lifting2=0*x2;
x3=702.0:0.1:720.0;
y3=xlsread('Steuerzeiten_Schrittweite_MTU4000.xlsx',1,'D7022:D7202');
Lifting3=spline(x3,y3);

%calculation and plot of speed intake

figure(2);hold on; grid on;
Speed1=fnder(Lifting1);
plot1=plot(x1,Speed1,'b');
Speed2=Lifting2;
plot2=plot(x2,Speed2,'b');
Speed3=fnder(Lifting3);
plot3=plot(x3,Speed3,'b');
hold off
legend([plot1,plot2,plot3],'Intake')
set(gca,'XTickLabel',{'OT','90','UT','270','ZOT','450','UT','630','OT'});
title('Intake Valve Speed')
xlabel('Crank Angle [°]')
ylabel('Speed [m/°]')
```

Answer (score 1):

`fnder` returns a struct, not an array for plotting. You must use `ppval` or `fnval` to evaluate it...

```
plot1 = plot(x1, ppval(Speed1,x1))
```

Docs:

https://lost-contact.mit.edu/afs/cs.stanford.edu/pkg/matlab-r2015b/matlab/r2015b/help/curvefit/examples/cubic-spline-interpolation.html

For using `csapi` see docs:
https://uk.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/csapi.html

```
% docs example
bcs = csapi( {x,y}, z ); 
fnplt( bcs )
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried it, but a constant function came out on my plot of Speed1, which is wrong, because I want to get a quadratic function in Speed1. I think, that the function of Lifting1 is linear, which makes Speed1 a constant funtion through differentiation with 'fnder', although I made it with 'csapi' instead of 'spline'. Does 'csapi' make the function cubic or not? I hope that you can help me about it.